# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) in /sysconfig.py

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, typeerror, windows-app-sdk

I was trying to install Flexible Atomic Code (python version, *https://github.com/flexible-atomic-code/fac*) on my Windows with Anaconda Prompt.

However, when I do `setup.py build` as to 'build everything needed to install' from `setup.py --help`, I got this error message:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\const.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\atom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\spm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\rfac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\consts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
copying python\aa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pfac
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py_multislice\fac-master\fac-master\setup.py", line 198, in <module>
    setup(name="PFAC",
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 316, in run
    customize_compiler(self.compiler)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\sysconfig.py", line 320, in customize_compiler
    cpp = cc + " -E"  # not always
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Which looks like that my C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\sysconfig.py file somehow has a TypeError?

Anyone has any idea what would be the issue and how to fix it? Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have compiler installed? The error says cc is None - all the signs suggest it means that it wasn't found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.